# How to simulate an external piece of hardware during the development of a LabView FPGA project

Tags: fpga, labview

I am working on a PXI system from National Instruments. It has an FPGA card that I have connected externally to a sensor.

I would like to know how to perform a "cycle accurate" simulation that includes a custom external stimulus that emulates the sensor.

There is a lot of example for simulating the labView -> FPGA -> labView interfaces, but nothing for LabView -> FPGA -> external hardware.

If it hasn't been a NI FPGA system, I would have written an HDL test bench for that, but within the NI FPGA framework, I can't figure out where to put my test bench.

In fact there is a place to put an HDL test bench, but as I said, the only available interface to test is the one between the labView code and the FPGA, and not between the FPGA and the external FPGA pins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a right pain (IMHO).

Last time I used Labview FPGA (admittedly a couple of years ago) it had no clue about cycle accurate simulation.

I had to build ordinary labview "testbenches" around each Sub VI - the Sub VI goes in a loop within the testbench VI.

Then link all the subvis together within single-cycle-timed-loops at the top-level. That top level is then not simulate-able, you just have to build it and see :(  As you probably agree - this is very alien to the usual FPGA flow.

Simulating right up to the pins (and then the hardware outside also) is just not possible (as far as I know, yet) - it is promised at some point...

Comment: FYI Now cycle accurate sim using modelSim or Isim is supported. And it works quite well. But the sim of the IOs is described as an "Optional" part of test benches. The way to do it is not explained anywhere but just mentioned in the help file...

Comment: Yes, I've heard tell of the cycle accurate simulation with ISIM... What I'd really have liked is to be able to simulate whole FPGAs (in non-real-time) just within the Labview environment.